# How to get huge amount of records in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am using laravel model to fetch the records from database. this time i am just getting 100-1000 rows but if it's more than 100 000, then I want to avoid out of memory exception. how can I get this in chunks ?

My Code

```
$getPatients = Patient::select('NameFirst', 'NameLast' , 'Email')->where([['MarketingOpt' , '=', '1'], ['synced' ,'=' , '0']])->get();
```

Comment: Normally you'll use pagination in this case :)

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with this result. If you just want to print the result, chunking will not help here.

Comment: For relevance: https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fqiita.com%2Fryo511%2Fitems%2Febcd1c1b2ad5addc5c9d

Answer (score 3):

To fetch // the number in paginate is the number of results you want returned

```
$getPatients = Patient::select('NameFirst', 'NameLast' , 'Email')->where([['MarketingOpt' , '=', '1'], ['synced' ,'=' , '0']])->paginate(100);
```

To Display

```
<div class="container">
  @foreach ($getPatients as $patient)
    {{ $patient->name }}
  @endforeach
</div>
{{ $getPatients->links() }} // this displays the previous and next links
```

Note this is for Laravel 5.5

See Here [Laravel Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination)

Comment: it will get only first 100 or it will divide them in chunks and will keep getting the record ?

Comment: @GoldSmith It depends on where do you want to use it. If you are using it in a API or web page, you just need to add  `page` parameter to your query URL to get further records.And, if you want to use the data internally just use the `chunk` method.

Comment: It server side so it will get the first 100, then if next is clicked it will get the next 100 - I assumed you were wanting to display it, if it is just for processing the answer below might be better

Comment: i am getting 5000 records at a time , so this will not work for this condition

Comment: Change the number to 5000

Answer (score 2):

You should use chunking [Laravel Queries: Chunking results](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#chunking-results)

Documentation only refers `DB::table('...')->chunk()` but this applies to Eloquent Models as well.

```
Patient::select('NameFirst', 'NameLast' , 'Email')
        ->where([['MarketingOpt' , '=', '1'], ['synced' ,'=' , '0']])
        ->chunk(100, function ($patients) {
    foreach($patients as $patient) {
        // do whatever you must do here
    }
});
```

Comment: Regarding Yeeooow answer, pagination is a concept that applies to views... OP doesn't mention displaying data, so he might as well just want to process data, e.g. a scheduled command.

Comment: yeah i am using this in a job , so I can't use pagination.

Comment: That's what I figured from your question. If you think so, please mark the answer as accepted.